# Extracting the Root of a Leftist Tree

Tags: binary-trees

A leftist tree is a variant of a binary heap, where the height of the left side of the tree is usually greater than the right side. Can a leftist tree's height ever increase after extracting the root? I am pretty sure it is impossible. How can a tree's height increase after taking away a node?

Answer (score 2):

When extracting the root, the subtrees of the root remain and have to merged. Merging two leftist trees is done by "zipping" the trees along their rightmost paths. Two short paths together might be rather long. Try some examples.

Comment: Mario Cervera did an example in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is, indeed, possible that the height of a leftist tree increases after an *extract minimum* operation. This is because, after extracting the root, the left and right subtrees have to be merged, and the [merge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree#Merging_height_biased_leftist_trees) operation is done recursively towards the right until you hit a node with an empty child. Below, you can see an example of a leftist tree that goes from a height of 2 to a height of 3 after extracting the minimum element, which, in this case, is 1.

[image: Example of a merge operation in a leftist tree]